# Play AudioBuffer in existing HTML5 audio tag

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, audiobuffer

I've created a website that contains an audio-tag as well as a working drop-area for file upload.

```
<body>
    <audio id="myPlayer" controls>Your browser does not support the audio-tag</audio>
    <div id="dropArea"></div>
</body>
```

A dragged audio-file then gets converted into an `ArrayBuffer` and ultimately an `AudioBuffer`.

```
let audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
let arrayBuffer = await readFileAsArrayBuffer(audioFile);

audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, buf => {
    console.log(buf);
});
```

The `AudioBuffer` can then be played in the function like this:

```
playSound(buffer) => {
  let source = context.createBufferSource();

  source.buffer = buffer;
  source.connect(context.destination);
  source.start(0);
}
```

**All of the above works fine, but that's not what I'm after.**

I want to the `AudioBuffer` to be played and controlled in the audio-player in my HTML instead. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, a [data URL](http://FileReader.readAsDataURL()) needs to be created from the uploaded file.

> The readAsDataURL method is used to read the contents of the specified Blob or File. When the read operation is finished, the readyState becomes DONE, and the loadend is triggered. At that time, the result attribute contains the data as a data: URL representing the file's data as a base64 encoded string.

**Example**

```js
// Helper Function
function readAsDataURL(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (file instanceof File) {
      reader.onload = () => {
        resolve(reader.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
      reject(new Error("This type of object is not supported"));
    }
  });
}

// Set URL for audio player
(async () => {
  const url = await readAsDataURL(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);
  const audioElement = document.querySelector("#audio-player");

  audioElement.src = url;
})();
```

Comment: Don't use a data URL here, instead create a blob URL from the file. But what happened to the AudioBuffer from the question?

Comment: The AudioBuffer has become obsolete, this is the desired way to play the file

Comment: But it's still there in the question you are answering...